# How can I stop Joomla (Apache) from caching the admin backend?

Tags: apache, joomla, joomla1.5

I've a big cache issue with my Joomla 1.5.26 (Apache/2.2.14 Ubuntu) administrator panel.

Everything is cached for about 15 minutes, and by *everything* I mean **everything**.

If I go to global configuration and change any value there, for example the Site Name from "MyTestSite" to "MyTestSite2", or the Feed length from 15 to 30 and save it a message is displayed that everything was saved and the cache was cleaned. If I go immediately to the global config again, I see that the old values (MyTestSite and 15) are still there. If I look into configuration.php I see that the file was correctly changed. Also, if I wait 15 minutes I can see the correct value. This is not related only to configuration, but even to article editing!

It's the same on 2 computers, and with Firefox, Chrome, and IE.

I've tried to fix it by placing a .htaccess in /admistrator/ to disable any caching, but to no avail.

I've tried this:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT"
</ifModule>
```

or this:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 minute"
```

What is going on here? (it was working fine for 2 years). How can I stop Joomla from caching the admin backend?

Comment: I'd contact hosting company. You pay them for a reason, right? You might inspect response headers sent along with the response, that should give you hints about caching options.

Comment: @piotr_cz there is no hosting company. it's a root server.

Comment: Usually things don't happen without a reason (server update?). Anyway, check the response headers (console > Network > index.php > Response Headers > Cache)